# The connection manager will not acquire a connection because the connection manager OfflineMode property is TRUE

Tags: oracle, ssis, etl

I am trying to store connections in the configuration table, but getting the below errors. **SSIS is not configured as Offline mode.**

> An error has occurred while connecting Oracle  Server: Exception from
> HRESULT: 0xC0202009. Validation error. Oracle to BO: The connection
> manager "Oracle  Server" will not acquire a connection because the
> connection manager OfflineMode property is TRUE. When the OfflineMode
> is TRUE, connections cannot be acquired.

The connection manager will not acquire a connection because the connection manager OfflineMode property is TRUE

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error is happening because TNS entry is mission in that machine.

Please verify if oracle TNS for the database is present in that machine or not?

You can find the TNS file in the below path.

```
C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin
```

If it is not there and try one more time.